# Define IsEnabled button property depending of the status validations

Tags: c#, button, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

I'm in my first Silverlight project 5 with C # and SQL, and since I have it configured validations in my metadata with RIA Services

in a form, I capture a table, there are 3 fields in textbox, are binding with the corresponding table, so when I capture something wrong makes me the textbox in red and tells me the corresponding error to the field in each of the textbox, so far so good

the question is, how do I quest the status of validations of these fields, so that only when there is no longer any error in any of the captured data in the textboxes, the Save button is enabled?

I need in xaml define the IsEnabled property of my Save button depending of the status validations

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think one way would be adding a read only bool property that checks the status of validation and returns the all-OK, with IsEnabled bound to it. You'd need to raise the PropertyChanged event for that bool each time a TextBox is validated (assuming INotifyPropertyChanged).
 
separately, you could research CommandBinding and CanExecute (I don't fully understand it yet)

Comment: ok, sounds good, I'll give a revised...

Comment: ...I continue investigating...